# Are you better off going with the BIG energy provider in town or a smaller competitor?

Tags: cost-cutting, household, electricity, utilities

I live in Maryland and we have our energy delivered from BGE (Baltimore Gas & Electric).  That means they manage and service the power lines and I have no choice in that matter.  We do however, have the option to have a different energy supplier. That means that I can purchase the energy from someone else at a different rate.  Naturally when we were signing up for utilities we got fast-tracked into buying our energy from and having it supplied by the same outfit.  I'm thinking of switching to a different energy provider. Has anyone ever purchased their energy from someone other than the 'Big Guy in Town'?  If so what was the outcome in terms of cost savings/increase?  Did you do a fixed or variable rate plan?  Were there any hidden fees to look out for?

Comment: Related: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/506/is-a-fixed-price-natural-gas-or-electricity-contract-likely-to-save-money

Comment: @Chris W. Rea - all those answers were about natural gas.  I want to know about electricity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in Connecticut and switched from the default CL-P to "Verde Energy" more than a year ago. The process was very smooth, no hidden fees, lower rate (not fixed). You are correct that you only save money on the supplier side. The delivery is still done by your regular company at the same price.

The saving is not huge because I have gas heat, maybe $5-$10 a month. if you have electric heat you'll save a lot more in winter months.

You might also get some perks (cash back, airline miles) when signing up depending on a promotion.